# Diamond number Shape Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a diamond shaped numbers with javascript
based from this template:

```js
function Pyramid(number) {
  document.write("<center>"); // this to align the output in center
  if (number > 0) {
    Pyramid(number - 1); //this is to move through the number of iterations
    for (j = 1; j <= number; j++) //this loop is to print the numbers in ascending order
    {
      document.write(" " + j);
    }

    for (k = number - 1; k > 0; k--) // this loop is to print the numbers in descending order
    {
      document.write(" " + k);
    }
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter a number</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="no" name="number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type=submit value="submit" id="pattern" onclick="Pyramid(document.getElementById('no').value)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The javascript above is rendering pyramid shaped numbers, can I somehow turn it to diamond shape, the rows still defined from the user input?
here are the image for the desired result.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QsNtpsHFgY-ornrruhiAGhZWUqA9GFxi

Comment: yes, what have you tried? i see no technical problem.

Comment: yes it's works
but somehow i want to turn the shapes of the numbers to be looks like on the image which i've provided.

Comment: what about the square calling  2 pyramids: 1 normal, and 1 reversed n-1. that would make a square, good luck implementing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want use recursive function like pyramid to build a diamond you can use this but you should use two separated function

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var temp2=temp*2;
function Pyramidstart(number) {
   
  document.write("<center>"); // this to align the output in center
  if (number > 0) {
    Pyramidstart(number - 1); //this is to move through the number of iterations
    for (j = 1; j <= number; j++) //this loop is to print the numbers in ascending order
    {
      document.write(" " + j);
    }

    for (k = number - 1; k > 0; k--) // this loop is to print the numbers in descending order
    {
      document.write(" " + k);
    }
    document.write("<br>");
  }
  
}
function p(x){
  
 document.write("<center>"); // this to align the output in center
  if (x < temp) {
    p(x + 1); //this is to move through the number of iterations
    for (j = 1; j <= x; j++) //this loop is to print the numbers in ascending order
    {
      document.write(" " + j);
    }

    for (k = x - 1; k > 0; k--) // this loop is to print the numbers in descending order
    {
      document.write(" " + k);
    }
    document.write("<br>");
  }
     
  
}
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter a number</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="no" name="number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type=submit value="submit" id="pattern" onclick="temp=document.getElementById('no').value;Pyramidstart(temp);p(1);"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```